# creating a popup that covers the screen

Tags: zenity

[image: does any one know how I would create a pop-up like this it needs to cover the whole screen]

so I want to create a pop-up that covers the whole screen
I have already had a look at zenity and it doesn’t really work

Answer (score 0):

You can use yad, which you can install from the Software Centre. The box it displays full screen looks awful but it works:

```
w=$(xdpyinfo | awk '/dimensions/{print $2}'|cut -f1 -dx); \
h=$(xdpyinfo | awk '/dimensions/{print $2}'|cut -f2 -dx); \
yad --title "Enter you password to perform adminitrative tasks" \
--entry --text "Enter your password" \
--width=$w --height=$h \
--center \
--button="gtk-cancel:252" \
--button="gtk-ok:0"
```

It works by using xdpyinfo to get the current resolution and passing the values as $w and $h to yad. The return codes will be 0 and 252 on clicking OK and Cancel respectively.

[image: screenshot]

`man yad` and `yad --help-all` provide assistance.

Comment: no because with that it doesn’t stop user from accessing the tool bar

Comment: Do you mean the panel? Users always have access to their panel once they are logged in...

Comment: no because when this popup is active you cannot click on anything